# Efficiently creating strict ByteStrings

Tags: haskell

Recently after running benchmarks on my project I've discovered that direct construction of strict bytestrings can be an order of magnitude faster than the one involving a builder.

E.g., an encoder implementation, which uses a builder:

```
encoder :: Int64 -> Data.ByteString.ByteString
encoder =
  Data.ByteString.Lazy.toStrict .
  Data.ByteString.Builder.toLazyByteString .
  Data.ByteString.Builder.int64BE
```

performs like 10 times worse than the one, which constructs the bytestring directly, and has several possibilities for further optimization:

```
encoder :: Int64 -> Data.ByteString.ByteString
encoder =
  unpackIntBySize 8

unpackIntBySize :: (Bits a, Integral a) => Int -> a -> Data.ByteString.ByteString
unpackIntBySize n x =
  Data.ByteString.pack $ map f $ reverse [0..n - 1]
  where
    f s =
      fromIntegral $ shiftR x (8 * s)
```

So my question is a two-fold:

1. Why is there no direct conversion from `Builder` to strict `ByteString`? It's annoying, because I often have to import `Data.ByteString.Lazy` just to use its `toStrict` function, because `Data.ByteString.Builder` exposes only `toLazyByteString`.
2. The mentioned experience however made me wonder, if it's not there for a reason. With the reason being that I'm applying an incorrect pattern of usage altogether. So, is it indeed incorrect and is there a better alternative? BTW, I know about `Data.ByteString.Builder.Prim`, but I doubt that using it in a case as above, would make much difference.

Comment: Interesting. For my daily work I assume that the way builder -> lazy ByteString -> strict Bytestring only pays off when building a large string from a large number of short ones. I usually do pack . show for converting from numbers to strict bs... don't know if it is good. Could you post some code that can be used for measuring performance? This looks like an interesting issue.

Comment: There are two branches of the "postgresql-binary" project, which implement the encoders using the two mentioned different strategies. Both come with benchmarks of encoding performance. Here's [a tree, in which the encoders are implemented using direct `ByteString` construction](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/postgresql-binary/tree/911a32110cfd618e2f7d377f4acc4c8f593f9acc), here's [the one revolving around `Builder`](https://github.com/nikita-volkov/postgresql-binary/tree/2fb6954968763621cbbdb8ba8505434ec2961b9e).

Comment: I think the trouble is `Builder` doesn't maintain a count of bytes required to write the resulting bytestring out, even though when you're not doing lazy streaming this is either statically-known (O(1)) or O(n)-but-probably-worth-it. You might check out `buffer-builder` and see if it does what you need. See discussion here:  https://github.com/chadaustin/buffer-builder/issues/7

Comment: Have you tried tweaking the allocation strategy?   Constructing a small bytestring using builder defaults to allocating a large bytestring,  then allocating a small bytestring of the correct length.    Also,  `blaze-builder` has a `writeToByteString` that might make using prims considerably more efficient (there's a function to turn prims into writes); it could be even better if you implement a `primFixedToByteString` and/or a `primBoundedToBytestring`.

Comment: @lpsmith Thanks. I'll consider that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Builder is not a zero-cost abstraction, it is optimized for large lazy strings. From the builder [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html):

> The current implementation is tuned for an average chunk size between 4kb and 32kb

In your case, builder allocates whole 4k chunk just to produce 8 bytes.

Compare with `pack`, which calculates necessary buffer size, allocates it and then fills it in a loop. The only source of inefficiency is a list of 8 `Word8` allocated upfront. Probably [`unfoldrN`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:unfoldrN) will be even more efficient.

Using builder to construct small strict bytestrings is sometimes convenient, but there are better ways.

Comment: Thanks! You mention "better ways". What do you imply? Are there any libraries you would suggest?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov I meant better for performance ad-hoc ways, like `unfoldrN`. I don't know any specific library that makes life easier, and I usually use bytestring builder when performance is not critical.

Comment: What about concatenating small strict bytestrings? Is it most efficient to just use `append` and/or `concat`?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `toLazyByteStringWith` from `Data.ByteString.Builder.Extra` to tune your `ByteString` construction.  This takes an `AllocationStrategy` that lets you tune the buffer size and growth rate.